# Valid Question?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across this question and I was unsure whether it fits SO requirements for a question. My initial thought was "No" because it seems like a Yes/No question with a prompt to do research for them.

But then I thought as I don't know G-Talk/W8-Messaging maybe this is an obscure enough question to warrant having to ask an expert.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107758/is-it-possible-to-write-windows-8-communication-protocol-provider-and-how

I seems like the correct course of action is probably to flag it with an explanation of my reasoning, but I don't think the moderators get back to people if they disagree with the reason. I'd like to know so I can flag up stuff correctly.

What is your opinion on the validity question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion and at a brief glance the question in question is not fitting because

- there's no real problem the OP is facing
- it's far too broad - books could and have probably been written on the subject
- it lacks research effort